# How many pages does this book have?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

> - Michael reads $3$ more pages more than on the last day he read.
> - On the 7th day, the amount of the pages he read is $25$.
> - If Michael finished reading this book in $10$ days, how many pages does this book have ?.

Before solving this question, I want to understand what question actually means and how to make the correct equations. Can you show it ?.

---

**My work:**

Let's call the pages $x$

$x +(x+3) + (x+6)... (x+21)$

Hence we get

$x+21 = 25 \implies  x = 4$

and

$\dfrac{x+(x+30)}{2}.10 = ?$

Regards

Comment: This doesn't look like linear algebra; can you show your work?

Comment: @AndrewLi See the new edit.

Comment: @AndrewLi Sorry everyone can do a mistake, there's nothing I can think right now.

Comment: Can't someone answer my question?

Comment: On the seventh day he reads $x+18$, not $x+21$.  This is an off-by-one error.  On the tenth day he reads $x+27$

Comment: Is this correct: $\dfrac{x+(x+27)}{2}.10 = ?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose he red $u_1$ pages the first day.

the day two, he red $u_2=u_1+3$.

the $n^{th}$  day, it is $$u_n=u_1+3 (n-1) $$

for $n=7$, we have $u_7=u_1+18=25$

thus $u_1=7$.

after ten days, he will have red
$$u_{10}=u_1+9×3=34 pages $$

Directly,
seventh day : 25 pages

eighth day :28

nineth day :31

last day :31+3=34.

Comment: It asks how many pages this book has. Also can I use this method for all kind of these questions?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Displayed $7 + 10 + 13 +..+34 = 70 + 0 + 3 + 6 +..+ 27 = 70 + 3\sum_{i=1}^{9} i = 70 + 3(45) = 205$

Comment: $$u_{n+1}=u_n+constant $$ for arithmetic and $$u_{n+1}=constant ×u_n $ for geometric.